# tag a user in an input box using '@'- angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for an angular directive or module that lets me tag a user in an input box. Ideally it would work like Facebook; when I type '@' it will execute an api call and will autocomplete a name that was returned from the api call.

Ex:"this is my example @user1, do you understand?"

Has anybody run into something like this?

Comment: Did you find anything like this? If you found something, please share it with us. Thanks in advance.